# Cassandra select query failure

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    col1 text,
    col2 text,
    col3 timestamp,
    cl4 int,
    col5 timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2, col3, col4)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (col2 DESC, col3 DESC,col4 DESC)
```

When I try querying from this table like:

```
select * from table where col1 = 'something' and col3 < 'something' 
  and col4= 12 limit 5 ALLOW FILTERING;
select * from table where col1 = 'something' and col4 < 23 
  and col3 >= 'something' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

I always get the error: `Clustering column "col4" cannot be restricted (preceding column "col3" is restricted by a non-EQ relation)` .

I tried to change the table creation by making col4, col3, col2, but the second query doesn't work and throw a similar error.
Any suggetion/advice to solve this problem.

We are on : Cassandra 3.0.17.7.

Comment: Please read this - [ClusteringColumns](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/whereClustering.html)

Comment: If your queries aren't going to utilize `col2` then why have it as a clustering column?  Get it out of your PRIMARY KEY def (or make it the last clustering column) and then you won't need `ALLOW FILTERING`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use non-equality condition only on the last column of partition of the query.

For example, you can do use `col1 = val and col2 <= ...`, or `col1 = val and col2 = val2 and col3 <= ...`, or `col1 = val and col2 = val2 and col3 = val3 and col4 <= ...`, but you can't do non-equality condition on several columns - that's how Cassandra reads data.